# How to fetch data from multiple web services in windows phone 7?

Tags: web-services, windows-phone-7, callback

iam new to windows phone7.

I have 3 web services.from three web services iam fetching data and stored into my local database.

iam placing a progress bar in the app which will show the progress of fetching data from these 3 web services.

i dont know how to update the progressbar with the fetching data from services.

please help me.

Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

How do u load this data?

Are you using a WebClient or did you include a WebReference?

edit:

Register the event for all 3 WebClients and do something like that:

```
// proptery to bind to the progress bar
public int ProgressBarPercentage 
{
    get { 
        return (_request1Percentage + _request2Percentage + request3Percentage)/3
    }
}
private int _request1Percentage;
private int _request2Percentage;
private int _request3Percentage;
```

In the event handler you just set the field for this handler and fire NotifyPropertyChanged for ProgressBarPercentage if you are using VM.

Comment: There is an event at the WebClient, called "DownloadProgressChanged". This should help ;)

Comment: hmm, i have three web services,

Comment: dont struggle, i find one solution and i implemented too, its working fine for me, i will post it in few minutes, thankyou

Answer (score 0):

i have taken one global static variable.

```
                    public static int progress = 0;
```

three web methods i have 
so three download string completed argumnets i have.

in each downloadstring complted evnt function i wrote

```
                    progress++;
```

in constructor i have taken one timer to check status of progress for every second

```
                         DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
        timer.Tick += delegate(object s, EventArgs args) { if (progress == 3) { NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Home.xaml", UriKind.Relative)); timer.Stop(); } };
        timer.Start();
```

so after downloading all content i moved to my next page
thankyou

Comment: So you just wanted to display a "loading bar" without displaying the percentage? Sorry seems I missunderstood your problem =/